# How to edit file path in clipboard with automator on OSX?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm working in an environment where we have more PCs than Macs, so the common way to point to files on a server is the windows style:
**file://W:**\Work\Client\etc

On OSX I'm using the "Copy Path to Clipboard" service with a shortcut.
This is what I get on my clipboard for the same location:
**\\server.inet**\Work\Client\etc

I want to replace the beginning of the path, and paste the result with a keyboard shortcut.

How can I do this with automator?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new service in Automator, i.e. with name **Copy Windows Path to Clipboard**. In Automator you define the service to take **Text** from **every application**.

The workflow step is to execute the following Applescript:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    if class of input is list then
        set selectedText to first item of input
    else
        set selectedText to input
    end if

    set searchList to {"\\\\server.inet"}
    set replaceList to {"file://W:"}

    repeat with i from 1 to count searchList
        set searchItem to item i of searchList
        set replaceItem to item i of replaceList

        if selectedText starts with searchItem then
            set selectedText to replaceItem & text ((length of searchItem) + 1) thru -1 of selectedText
        end if
    end repeat
    set the clipboard to selectedText
    return input
end run
```

You have to configure your substitutions, here I defined the server you mentioned: **\\server.inet** will be replaced by **file://W:**

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: you just posted a chunk of code. How to use it with automator?

Comment: No, I did not, the post contains all the things you have to do like "Create a new service", configure the input and execute Applescript with the code mentioned. Have fun!